# Invoking spring bean for jbpm service task

Tags: jbpm

JBPM process (bpmn2 file) allows to add a 'service task'. The default 'Service Task' has been registered to use 'ServiceTaskHandler'.

```
ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Service Task", new ServiceTaskHandler());
```

It works ok if the service task class has no dependency, *but fails when it's a spring bean.*

I looked into each and every class of kie-spring module, but couldn't find any similar implementation as ServiceTaskHandler, though it's easier to implement myself.

Could someone please help me to understand if implementing ourself could create any issue?

I feel there must be some reason for not implementing within the spring integration with jbpm.

I am using the doc

```
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.48.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_spring
```

The document refer to create 'Custom Work Item' for each service task, but ***it would become cumbersome if the service tasks are in bigger numbers and each service task is a spring bean.***

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a custom spring work item handler that takes in input a 'serviceName'.

You then create an interface of a generic task like so

```
public interface CustomTask {
   
   Map<String, Object> execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemHanlder wiHandler);

}
```

Then starting from this interface you can just create as many tasks as you want annotating them with the Spring annotation @Component(value="serviceNameYouPutOnTheInputOfTheTask")

From the work item handler (within the execute method) you'll then have to call the application context and retrieve the bean with the name = 'serviceName' like so

```
context.getBean(serviceName);
```

This way you'll have only ONE work item handler, handling all of the required spring beans to be called
This is by far the best solution I could find for myself.